# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'

Tags: asp.net, email

TRYING TO SEND mail with document name and then value which admin select from dropdown like approve/reject/pending 
for this i try this code

```
Label DocName = ((Label)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("DocName"));
DropDownList dropdownvalue =(DropDownList)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("lblvalue"));
Label Label2 = ((Label)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("Label2"));
string docname = String.Empty;
string dropdownvalues = String.Empty;
string emailId = String.Empty;

if (DocName.Text.ToString() != ""){
    docname = DocName.Text.ToString();
}else{
    docname = "Unavailable";
}

if (dropdownvalue.SelectedItem.ToString() != ""){
    dropdownvalues = dropdownvalue.SelectedItem.ToString();
}else{
    dropdownvalue = "Unavailable";
}
```

HTML:

```
<td> 
  <asp:Label ID="lblvalue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ApproveID") %>' Visible = "false" /> 
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" class="vpb_dropdown" DataTextField="ApproveType" DataValueField="ApproveID" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Pending" selected="selected" Value="3">
    </asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem Text="Approve" Value="1">
    </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Reject" Value="2">
    </asp:ListItem> 
  </asp:DropDownList> 
</td>
```

but here occurs in this code

```
 dropdownvalue = "Unavailable";
```

Error
    Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Mistake is that in you HTML lblvalue is a Label and you are trying to cast a Dropdowm:

```
//HTML
    <asp:Label ID="lblvalue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ApproveID") %>' Visible = "false" /> 

//CodeBehind
    DropDownList dropdownvalue = 
                   ((DropDownList)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("lblvalue"));
```

I think you are looking for to get the value in a label:

```
Label dropdownvalue = 
                   ((Label)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("lblvalue"));
```

But whether you want to get and set the value in the DropDown:

```
DropDownList dropdownvalue = 
                       ((DropDownList)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("DropDownList4"));
```

I hope that you see the Error.

Comment: @user2931015 Look this line becouse you are try to cast a Label like a DropDown.

Comment: i dont understand whay your are trying to say

Comment: @user2931015 The findControl is trying to find a **Label** and It is trying to cast a **label** in a **DropDown**. Becouse that you are getting the error.

Comment: Or look What is lblvalue, and check if that is the name of the dropdownlist.

Comment: look this is dropdown control
<td> <asp:Label ID="lblvalue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ApproveID") %>' Visible = "false" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" class="vpb_dropdown" DataTextField="ApproveType" DataValueField="ApproveID" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged">        <asp:ListItem Text="Pending" selected="selected" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="Approve" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="Reject" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
 </td>